# Can’t find any information about original_transaction_id in Family sharing

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, in-app-subscription

Can’t find any information about original_transaction_id in Family sharing.  Can anyone say will original_transaction_id one for all members who get a subscription with Family sharing or original_transaction_id will be unique for all users?
I need determine all members from all Family Sharing to give them ability to use the same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is answer that i got on apple support forum:

> They will each have a unique Original transaction id, the StoreKit
> transactional data does not support identifying a family cohort. We
> welcome feedback to share with the teams. FeedbackAssistant.Apple.com